# Proving that these conditions are sufficient for making two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ equivalent.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[Wikipedia mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics)  -without proof nor proper sources- the following two conditions as sufficient for making two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ on $X$ equivalent (i.e. they generate the same topology on $X$):

1. There exists ([Efe Ok, p. 137](https://books.google.fr/books?id=pYJmnnnA1dkC&pg=PA137), footnote 12) some function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that:
   1.1. $f$ is continuous.
   1.2. $f$ is strictly increasing i.e. $x<y\Rightarrow f(x)<f(y)$.
   1.3. $f$ is subadditive i.e. $f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y)$.
   1.4. $d_2 = f\circ d_1$.
2. For any $x\in X$ there exist positive constants $\alpha, \beta$ such that
   $$\alpha d_1(x,y)\le d_2(x,y) \le \beta d_1(x,y)\ \ \ \text{ for all } y\in X.$$

---

How may one prove (although being directed to a prove would suffice) that the two conditions above imply $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent?

Comment: Use the theorem that says that two bases generate the same topology if any set in either basis contains a nontrivial set from the other basis. For example, the second condition shows that you can squeeze an open ball from one metric inside any open ball from the other metric. Since the open balls generate the topology, this implies the topologies are the same.

Comment: You can alternatively show that a set $F$ is closed in $d_1$ iff it is closed in $d_2$.

Comment: You don't need both conditions 1 and 2. Condition 1 is equivalent [to metric equivalence :-)] and condition 2 is also equivalent.